# Display empty text when there are no items in ListView Windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, empty-list

I'm trying to display an empty text message inside a listview when I have no items inside it (that's when the form is initialized).

I've tried searching different method out of which one is using the `OnPaint() event , but that didn't work out well...

Can someone help me out ?
` 
Edit: this is one of the methods I've tried:

```
  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m.Msg == 20)
            {
                if (this.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                    _b = true;
                    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
                    int w = (this.Width - g.MeasureString(_msg,
                      this.Font).ToSize().Width) / 2;
                    g.DrawString(_msg, this.Font,
                      SystemBrushes.ControlText, w, 30);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (_b)
                    {
                        this.Invalidate();
                        _b = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (m.Msg == 4127) this.Invalidate();
        }
```

Comment: Did you forget to check for null and if Items.Count < 0?  The items count will be -1 when the form constructor is executing and your code could get call during this time.  If always check if a control item count is less than zero to prevent exceptions from occurring when the constructor of the form is running.

Comment: @jdweng Yes I've checked for that, for some reason it doesn't works at all..  This is why I'm looking for a different method to display an empty text

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: No, the form runs without exceptions, but the listview shows just header columns :/

Comment: You can handle `0xF` message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle [`WM_PAINT(0xF)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213(v=vs.85).aspx) message and check if there is no item in `Items` collection, draw a string in center of your `ListView`. For example:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;

public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public MyListView()
    {
        EmptyText = "No data available.";
    }
    [DefaultValue("No data available.")]
    public string EmptyText { get; set; }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == 0xF)
        {
            if (this.Items.Count == 0)
                using (var g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle))
                    TextRenderer.DrawText(g, EmptyText, Font, ClientRectangle, ForeColor);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I implement this on the form when displaying items on the form ?

Comment: P.S. The reason I'm asking this is because the listview I have on the form is just simply dragged and then used in code behind, that's why I'm quite sure how to use this code to combine it ? :)

Comment: This is a new `MyListView` control which is derived from `ListView`. So when you added this control to your project, you can drop an instance of it from toolbox to your form and use it like any other control.

Comment: oh!! One moment I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Don't forget to build the project, then it will be available in toolbox in first components tab.

Comment: teşekkürler arkadas :)